# Point Estimator.

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

When the point estimator under consideration has a pdf , the 
   $P[T=\tau(\theta)]=0 $ ,
where $\tau(.)$ is some function of parameter $\theta$ and 
$T$ is an estimator of $\tau(\theta)$.

But I did many exercises to find point estimators of the parameters of density functions..

For example the two point estimators of mean , $\mu$ and  variance $\sigma^2$ of normal density are $\bar x$ and $\frac{n}{n-1}S^2$,  respectively.

But for the following statement, do those need to be zero ?

" When the point estimator under consideration has a pdf , the 
   $P[T=\tau(\theta)]=0 .$ "

Comment: I think this just means $P(X = x) = 0$ whenever $X$ is a continuous distribution.